# Query two tables by a condition from a third table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, jdbc

Here is my case:

```
  table a
  table b
  table c (type int)

if c.type = 1 select all rows in table a
if c.type = 2 select all rows in table b
```

Currently my solution is find all rows in 3 tables and handle result to get values but it's really bad.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what the relationship is between the tables.  The expression `c.type` refers to a rows, not to the entire table.  So, let me assume that `c.type = 1` means "there exists a row where `c.type = 1`".

The solution to this problem is then conditional `union all`:

```
select a.*
from tablea a
where exists (select 1 from tablec c where c.type = 1)
union all
select b.*
from tableb b
where exists (select 1 from tablec c where c.type = 2)
```

This assumes that the columns are the same in `a` and `b`.  Otherwise, you need to specify the correct set of columns.